# https redirection doesn't work using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, http-redirect

I can't make url redirection to work and I am struggling since couple of days.

I have been searching url redirection on google using .htaccess and tried many examples but non of them work for my below problem. so please help.

I just want to redirect...

domain.com/admin -> https://www.domain.com/admin
www.domain.com/admin -> https://www.domain.com/admin

Note: normal non-www -> https and www->https redirection is working only sub url redirection problem.

Comment: my .htaccess is as below...

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: @anubhava - if you can help...thanks